# ruby on rails: add a page that displays many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have 3 tables: one contains illnesses, one contains symptoms and one is a many-to-many illness_symptom table. I want to add a hyperlink from my illness page which will lead the user to a new page that contains the symptoms of this certain illness (sorted alphabetically).

I'm new in ROR so I don't really know where to place this new page in the Project Tree and how to add a route to it.

I've added a directory called "Pages", under which I placed my new file "symptomsForIllness.html.erb". In addition I added a hyperlink in the illness/show html:

```
<%= link_to 'Symptoms',symptomsForIllness_path(@illness) %>
```

And I also tried to add the following route to routes.rb:

```
match '/symptomsForIllness_path' => 'Pages#symptomsForIllness'
```

I get the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `symptomsForIllness_path' for #<#<Class:0x3f1fbc0>:0x32d0060>):
    10: <%= link_to 'Back', illnesses_path %>
    11: <br />
    12: <%= link_to 'symptoms',symptomsForIllness_path(@illness) %>
  app/views/illnesses/show.html.erb:13:in`_app_views_illnesses_show_html_erb___154118681_26683248'
  app/controllers/illnesses_controller.rb:19:in `show'

Could you please tell me where to place such files in the directory tree (files that represent many to many relations) and how to avoid this error?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Plz read rails routing guide...u r doing all in a very wrong way)

Comment: I read it, I still don't know where to begin. Where should I place this page?  should it be independent (and then it's ok to place it under the pages directory)? I know I need to add a method in the pages controller, I'm just not sure what is the convention in this case... should I create a separate controller for this many to many relation?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#in routes.rb
resources :symptoms :only => [:index] do
  get 'illnesses', :on => :member
end

resources :illnesses :only => [:index] do
  get 'symptoms', :on => :member
end
```

in view path_helpers

```
illnesses_symptom_path(@symptom) #symptoms controller, illnesses action

symptoms_illness_path(@symptom) #illnesses controller, symptoms action
```

Comment: Thanks, The path_helpers are generated automatically, aren't they? In addition, can I see which path_helpers were generated for my project?